# How can i get download link with watin?

Tags: c#, watin

There is a HTML code, in another website :

```
<form action="down.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" id="mid" value="pg/K/c3scJubYvZj8UI=" />
    <span><input class="btnff" type="submit" value="downloadd" /></span>
</form>
```

I want to download with Watin and c sharp :

```
 WatiN.Core.Button btn1 = browser1.Button(Find.ByValue("downloadd")) as WatiN.Core.Button;
                    btn1.Click();
```

When I click on it, download start with IDM(Internet download manager).
The Link does not exist in Source code, even after I click on Button.

How can I get Link with Watin(Not IDM) and download with c sharp to save in a specific folder?

Comment: I don't know `WaitN`, but I think it handles redirects and stuff like that for you. To get the acutal download link you have to disable this behavior (if possible) or do it manually with a `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. There you could disable automatic handling and extract the download link from the received http-redirect or html-redirect.

Comment: idm does not change the download link. if u want to download yourself don't call button.click, just get the link and download yourself.

Comment: How can I get the Link with watin?